# Filter option using regular expression

Tags: oracle

I have requirement for the filter the names in the table.

Example Table Name :- student

Columns                    :- Name, Class.

```
The date is like
```

Name ----Class

HIGHSPEED ---C

HIGHSPEED11 ---C1

HIGHSPEED22 ---C2

NORMAL-------------N

NORMAL1-------------N1

NORMAL2-------------N2

Like this i have data SRQ, PWE ...

My requirement is I need to remove some data using a name...

```
SELECT distinct name  FROM student WHERE UPPER (name) LIKE 'SRP%'
                           Or UPPER (name) LIKE 'HIGHSPEED%'
                           Or UPPER (name) LIKE 'SRQ%'
                           Or UPPER (name) LIKE 'PWE%'
                           Or UPPER (name) LIKE 'SPINTERFACE%'
                           Or UPPER (name) LIKE 'SRM%'
```

Instead of using OR condition, please let me know any other option... ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Oracle user, but a quick look through their docs indicates Oracle supports POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). So a regular expression that matches the names in your query would be:

```
^(SRP|HIGHSPEED|SRQ|PWE|SPINTERFACE|SRM)
```

It looks like Oracle supplies a REGEXP_LIKE function, so your query could be re-written using the regular expression as:

```
SELECT distinct name FROM student WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(name), '^(SRP|HIGHSPEED|SRQ|PWE|SPINTERFACE|SRM)');
```

I'm afraid I don't have access to Oracle to test but that's what the regular expression will look like.